# Magento How to include shopping cart block like this (picture)

Tags: shopping-cart

im looking for a solution for my magento shop how to include a shopping cart block like this one in the header.

[image: cart]

When you click on this block it open a information how much products you have in your cart.

Whats the code for this solution. Maybe it is a extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the rwd theme of magento1.9, it is already built in it else you will have to create it doing some css and jquery customization in Magento shopping basket left-bar widget.

You can make it following this tutorial [Display Products in shopping cart in a drop down format in Magento](http://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/display-products-in-shopping-cart-in-a-drop-down-format-in-magento/)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but i have do everything what stands in the tutorial, but it nothing work. I have created the new cart_top.phtml and put the jquery in the header of the file. Then i include the code getLayout()-&gt;createBlock(‘checkout/cart_sidebar’)-&gt;setTemplate(‘checkout/cart/cart_top.phtml’)-&gt;toHtml(); in my topmenu.phtml but nothing visible.

Comment: It should work because the screenshot you see is the implemted one and i have done that.. you might be going wrong somewhere

Comment: Okay i have find out how to convert the code to php. But my next problem is, that the jquery script isnt fired when i open the side. The block is always out.

Comment: there might be some jquery conflict on your website... i can't predict it but you can try using noconflict

Comment: Please look at my code here http://pastebin.com/MKszjWyb

Comment: Have you wrote css for the added class... you need to write css for display and hide the div

Comment: no not really. In the tutorial there are no css code. Which code can you prefer me ?

Comment: you will have to write css on your own. Simple display:none and display:block will work with transition effect also does the slide-up, slide-down is working?? it should be working or else check console for jquery error

Comment: Its working now!! i have to replace ` to ' . Many failures by copying code inside notepad++ >_< sorry but im not a pro in programming.

Comment: Great it helped you... please mark the answer as accepted so future user can benifit from it